# ContentType for HttpHeaders when uploading File in FormData

Tags: angular, .net-core, http-headers, content-type, image-upload

I have an Angular Single Page Application which calls a .NET Core API.

The default set up creates HttpHeaders to pass a jwt token to the API and sets the content-type to **application/json; charset=utf-8**

To extend this application, I've been following "Angular Image Upload Made Easy" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkvqLNcJz3Y), but with my default headers, the image in FormData in the API was always null.

So I changed the content-type to **multipart/form-data**, but got the same result.

After much experimentation, I discovered that ***not setting a content-type at all works***. I can still pass my jwt to authenticate the user and the image now uploads without any problems.

So, is it safe to leave out content-type in request options, or would it be better to insert the "correct" type and what would that be?

(In the example in the video, request options are added to monitor progress of the upload, but no headers are included - reportProgress:true, observe:'events')

Answer (score 1):

This should not be a problem but you still have to make file type verification in your .NET core API.

In requests, (such as POST or PUT), the client tells the server what type of data is actually sent.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)

Comment: Thanks, I'll proceed with what works, but it does seem odd that content-type is not a requirement and that setting what appears to be a correct content type does not work.

Comment: You can log the content type received if you want to see what it's when you receive it. The one you were using must have had errors in it.

Comment: Setting content type manually to multipart/form-data does not work 

But when the content type is added automatically (a value is not set), I detect the following in the API:

multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryGDW5TnJTDKHj50zI

So for my file upload to work, I let  the automagic happen